# can't build maven project in c:\\program files(X86)

Tags: maven-3

My maven project is not building when placed in `c:\program` file while build is successful if placed in any other folder?

It throws error :

> could not find main class files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most likely the root cause is Windows protecting `C:\Program Files\` folder from unauthorized access. Only elevated programs can modify files under this folder. This could result in Maven being unable to create class files. I would expect it to complain sooner, however.